# Error in c("K", "K", "K" : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Tags: r

Hi I am try to change the value in a column depending on the character present in another column.

my data is as below

```
    row.names   STATE__ COUNTY  STATE   COUNTYNAME  EVTYPE  FATALITIES  INJURIES    PROPDMG PROPDMGEXP  CROPDMG CROPDMGEXP
1   1   1   97  AL  MOBILE  TORNADO 0   15  25  K   0    
2   53  1   33  AL  COLBERT TORNADO 0   1   25  K   0    
3   105 1   99  AL  MONROE  TORNADO 0   0   0.25    K   0    
4   157 1   127 AL  WALKER  TORNADO 4   15  25  K   0    
5   313 1   65  AL  HALE    TORNADO 0   0   25  K   0    
6   625 1   33  AL  COLBERT TORNADO 0   0   250 K   0
```

my code is as below

```
evtype_cal_dat3  <- mutate(evtype_dat3,DMG = ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == "K"|"k", PROPDMG * 1000, ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == "M" | "m", PROPDMG * 10^6, ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == "B",PROPDMG * 10^9,PROPDMG))))
Error in c("K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K", "M", "K", "K", "K", "K", "K",  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

why am I getting that error? I converted CROPDMG to as.numeric and the CROPDMGEXP to as.character. yet I am getting errors.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: `PROPDMGEXP == "K"|"k"` is not correct.  It should be `%in%` i.e `PROPDMGEXP %in% c("K", "k")`.  After correct that, it works for me `mutate(df1, DMG = ifelse(PROPDMGEXP %in%  c("K", "k"), PROPDMG * 1000, ifelse(PROPDMGEXP %in% c( "M" , "m"), PROPDMG * 10^6, ifelse(PROPDMGEXP == "B",PROPDMG * 10^9,PROPDMG))))`

Comment: @ akrun, Many thanks, will correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  If you want to use a filter by distinct character strings, use the following:

```
evtype_cal_dat3 <- evtype_cal_dat3 %>% filter(PROPDMGEXP %in% c("K","k"))
```